# How do i access an object in an array in php, in a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I thought it would be like this:

```
class  Object
    {
       public $ID;
       public $Name;

     }
```

I fill the array using `array_push($Objects, $Obj);`

```
for ( $d = 0; $d < count($Objects); $d++)
{
   echo $Objects[$d]->Name;
}
```

php gives me an error saying "Trying to get property of non-object in ..."

Comment: What does this array of objects look like?

Comment: try using foreach(), it's a little cleaner. `foreach($Objects AS $data){  echo $data->Name); }`

Comment: before the loop, do a `var_dump($Objects);` - whats in it?

Comment: What outputs `var_dump($Objects)`?

Comment: $Obj = new Object();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class  Object
        {
           public $ID;
           public $Name = 'N';

         }

    $Objects =array();

    array_push($Objects,new Object());
    array_push($Objects,new Object());
    array_push($Objects,new Object());

    foreach($Objects as $obj){

        echo $obj->Name;
    }

    // NNN
```